# Where is `%p` useful with printf?

Tags: c++, c, printf

After all, both these statements do the same thing...

```
int a = 10;
int *b = &a;
printf("%p\n",b);
printf("%08X\n",b);
```

For example (with different addresses):

```
0012FEE0
0012FEE0
```

It is trivial to format the pointer as desired with `%x`, so is there some good use of the `%p` option?

Comment: By using '%p' you print the address of the variable in question, "The void * pointer argument is printed in hexadecimal (as if by %#x or %#lx)."

Comment: In C++, you can use (void *) typecast: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657123/how-to-simulate-printfs-p-format-when-using-stdcout

Answer (score 150, accepted):

They do not do the same thing. The latter [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) statement interprets `b` as an `unsigned int`, which is wrong, as `b` is a pointer.

Pointers and `unsigned int`s are not always the same size, so these are not interchangeable. When they aren't the same size (an increasingly common case, as 64-bit CPUs and operating systems become more common), `%x` will only print half of the address. On a Mac (and probably some other systems), that *will* ruin the address; the output will be wrong.

Always use `%p` for pointers.

Comment: %p will also use an adequate textural representation for pointer for the platform.  On platforms where it is common to represent pointer in hex, this won't make a difference as long as the size is correct but for a segmented architecture (do you remember DOS?) it may use a segment:offset representation.

Comment: One also needs to cast `b` to `void *` with the `%p` format - this is one of the few instances in C where one needs a cast.

Comment: "All the world's a VAX!" syndrome.

Comment: Adding to @AlokSinghal comment: for GCC if you compile with the ```-Wextra``` flag you will get appropriate warnings for incorrect types in ```printf```.  To make the warning go away you need to use the correct form and cast to ```void*``` which can be helpful.

Answer (score 9):

At least on one system that is not very uncommon, they do not print the same:

```
~/src> uname -m
i686
~/src> gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-pc-linux-gnu
[some output snipped]
gcc version 4.1.2 (Gentoo 4.1.2)
~/src> gcc -o printfptr printfptr.c
~/src> ./printfptr
0xbf8ce99c
bf8ce99c
```

Notice how the pointer version adds a `0x` prefix, for instance. Always use %p since it knows about the size of pointers, and how to best represent them as text.

Comment: "...that is not very uncommon". Nice :)

Answer (score 5):

The size of the pointer may be something different than that of `int`. Also an implementation could produce better than simple hex value representation of the address when you use `%p`.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot depend on `%p` displaying a `0x` prefix. On Visual C++, it does not. Use `%#p` to be portable.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? I cannot find anything about # used in conjunction with %p. I have checked: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aky45ct(v=vs.71).aspx http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Comment: PC-Lint doesn't like it, but it works in Visual Studio. Unfortunately it prepends '0X' not '0x', making the actual value hard to read. Presumably this is due to a missing '%P' variant.  All told, this format specifier suffers from the problem of all 'platform dependent' implementations, that you can't really control what you're going to get. I use '0x%p' at the risk of getting a double 0x0X at the start.  Rather undermines using it, because you know exactly what you're getting with %x.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be at all portable, even between VC versions. For example, VS 2013 (12.0.40629.00 update 5) prefixes '0X' for "%#p" but has no prefix for "%p". But VC 19.00.23506 doesn't prefix for either "%p" or "%#p". Then G++ 5.4.0 prefixes with "0x" for both "%p" and "%#p" (and using "%#p" gives a G++ warning). In short, you can't rely on the format of this at all.

Answer (score 2):

`x` is Unsigned hexadecimal integer ( 32 Bit )

`p` is Pointer address

See [printf on the C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/). Even if both of them would write the same, I would use `%p` to print a pointer.

Comment: yeah, I already went through that page. What I wanted to know was why would you `use %p to print a pointer`. Anyways, Peter Hosey's answer answers my doubt.

Comment: They busted your link. Moved to https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 2):

When you need to debug, use printf with `%p` option is really helpful. You see 0x0 when you have a NULL value.

Comment: On gcc (4.4.7, at least), a NULL value shows as `(nil)`  -- including the parentheses. There seems to be a lot of implementation-specific variation in `%p`

Answer (score -2):

`x` is used to print t pointer argument in hexadecimal.

A typical address when printed using `%x` would look like `bfffc6e4` and the sane address printed using `%p` would be `0xbfffc6e4`

Comment: No, `%x` is used to  print a value of type `unsigned int` in hexadecimal. There's absolutely no guarantee that `unsigned int` is the same size as `void *`, and it's a bad idea to assume so in code.