# How to simulate printf's %p format when using std::cout?

Tags: c++, gcc, iostream

```
unsigned char *teta = ....;
...
printf("data at %p\n", teta); // prints 0xXXXXXXXX
```

How can I print variable address using `iostream`s? Is there a `std::`??? feature like `std::hex` to do this kind of conversion (address -> string), so `std::cout << std::??? << teta << std::endl` will print that address?

(no sprintf's, please ;))

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Cast to `void*`:

```
unsigned char* teta = ....;
std::cout << "data at " << static_cast<void*>(teta) << "\n";
```

iostreams generally assume you have a string with any `char*` pointer, but a `void*` pointer is just that - an address (simplified), so the iostreams can't do anything other than transforming that address into a string, and not the content of that address.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on wheter or not you want to use more formatting options printf gives, you could consider using [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/)

By it, you could format a string just like you'd do with printf, and afterwards print it out with `std::cout`

However, this would involve using a temporary char array so the choice depends.

An example:

```
unsigned char *teta = ....;
...
char formatted[ 256 ]; //Caution with the length, there is risk of a buffer overflow
sprintf( formatted, "data at %p\n", teta );
std::cout << formatted;
```

Comment: and in this case (void *) casting is better - no temporary array will fit a single line of debugging (log4cxx) code..

Comment: instead of unsafe `sprintf` you could consider `snprintf` or (better) Boost.Format.