# Get the address of class's object in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-address

Suppose I have a C++ class as follows:

```
class Point {
// implementing some operations
}
```

Then:

```
Point p1;
Point p2 = p1;
```

If I want to know the address of p2, then I can use `&p2`. But how can I get the address that p2 stores? Because p2 is not a pointer, so I cannot just use `cout << p2;`

Comment: huh? p2 stores no address, as it's not a pointer. It stores user-defined data (it's member variables).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What's wrong with the following:

```
cout << &p2;
```

As you say, `p2` is not a pointer. Conceptually it is a block of data stored somewhere in memory. `&p2` is the address of this block. When you do:

```
Point p2 = p1;
```

...that data is copied to the block 'labelled' `p1`.

> But how can I get the address that p2 stores?

Unless you add a pointer member to the `Point` data structure, it doesn't store an address. As you said, it's not a pointer.

P.S. The [hex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) stream operator might be useful too:

```
cout << hex << &p2 << endl;
```

Comment: [Beware if the object is actually a `char`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657123/how-to-simulate-printfs-p-format-when-using-stdcout/5657144#5657144).

Comment: What's wrong with answers that start with, "what's wrong with"?

Answer (score 4):

By doing

```
Point p2 = p1;
```

you simply copy the values of p2 onto p1 (most likely). The memory is independent. 
If you did instead:

```
Point* p2 = &p1;
```

then p2 will be a pointer onto p1 (printing its value will give you the begining of the memory block, you could then try the sizeof to get the size of the block).

Comment: Hi Hauron. "copy the values of p2 onto p1" should be the other way around. Good example with the pointer, but should be `sizeof` (no underscore) and anyway you can get the size of the object with `sizeof(Point)` or `sizeof p1` as well as `sizeof *p2` for your pointer version thereof.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer proposes the use of operator `&` to obtain the address of an object.

As of C++11, this solution does not work if the object class defines/overloads operator `&`.

In order to get the address of an object, from C++11, the template function `std::addressof()` should be used instead.

```
Point p1;
Point* p2 = std::addressof(p1);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/addressof/