# Printing array element memory adresses C and C++, why different output?

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to simulate printf's %p format when using std::cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657123/how-to-simulate-printfs-p-format-when-using-stdcout)

I try to print out the array element memory addresses in C and C++.

In C:

```
char array[10];
int i;
for(i =0; i<10;i++){
    printf(" %p \n", &array[i]);
}
```

I got the memory addresses: `0xbfbe3312`, `0xbfbe3313`, `0xbfbe3314`, `...`.

But if I try to make the same in C++:

```
char array[10];
for(int i =0; i<10;i++){
    std::cout<<&array[i]<<std::endl;
}
```

I got this output:

> �
>
> P��
>   ��
>   �
>
> k�
>   �

Why is it different? Should I use the `cout` differently in C++ to print out the memory addresses? How should I print out the memory addresses?

Comment: In C, the `"%p"` expects a value of type `void*`. You're passing a value of type `char*` and that invokes **Undefined Behaviour**. So, because `printf` acceps a variable number of arguments and the compiler can't convert values by itself, cast the argument: `printf(" %p \n", (void*)&array[i]);`

Answer (score 10):

Cast the address to `void*` before printing, in C++ the `operator<<` of `ostream` is overloaded for `(const) char*` so that it thinks it's a c-style string:

```
char array[10];
for(int i =0; i<10;i++){
    std::cout << static_cast<void*>(&array[i]) << std::endl;
}
```

Also see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657123/how-to-simulate-printfs-p-format-when-using-stdcout).

Answer (score 2):

The type of `&array[i]` is `char*`, and so `cout<<` thinks that you want to print a string.

Answer (score 2):

`std::cout` does not necessarily treat pointers as pointers. A `char*` pointer could be a `string`, for instance. Taking the address of an element in a `char` array basically outputs the substring from that point.

Answer (score 2):

You must cast `&array[i]` to `void*`

```
for(int i =0; i<10;i++){
    std::cout<<(void*)&array[i]<<std::endl;
}
```

This is because C++ streams work differently for different types. For example when you pass `char*` to it, your data is treated as a C-string - thus it is printed as a list of characters.

You must explicitly tell C++ that you want to print an address by casting.

By the way `(void*)` is not the best way to do that as you should avoid C-like casting. Always use C++-style casting (`static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`). In this case `static_cast` would do the job.