# How to print out memory addresses of C-String?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory, c-strings

The function prints the addresses of each memory location of the dynamic array. Is this the right way?

```
int main()
{
    char str[] = "This is a test";
    printAddresses(str, strlen(str));
}

template <class type>
void printAddresses(type *item, int n)
{
    cout << "Printing Addresses..." << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Index " << i << ": " << ((&item) + i)  << endl;
    }

}
```

I've also heard that I should use:

```
cout << "Index " << i << ": " << (void*) &item[i] << endl;
```

but that gives me different memory address. I'm not sure which one is right.

Comment: Cast to `void*` to print the address.

Comment: Break with the debugger and see.

Comment: `cout << "Index " << i << ": " << (void*)((&item[i]))  << endl;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct address is the one you obtain when printing `(void*)&item[i]`.

`item` is already a pointer; so is `&item[i]`. You are interested in printing the value of this pointer, you need to cast it to `void*` before calling `<<` on it.

When you print `((&item) + i)` you are making an extra level of indirection (`&item` is a pointer-to-pointer), so you print the address of `item`-the-pointer, not the address of what `item` is pointing to.

**Note::** Starting with C++11 you can use [`std::addressof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) function in place of operator `&` for better readability and to avoid potential issues when `T` provides an overload for operator `&`:

```
cout << "Index " << i << ": " << std::addressof(item[i]) << endl;
```

Comment: In that case, why would  ``cout << "Index " << i << ": " << (item + i)  << endl;``

not work?

Comment: @user3577478 That is an excellent question! The reason why this wouldn't work is that operator << has an overload for char pointer, which treats that pointer as a null-terminated C string, printing its content. By casting to void pointer you force an overload that prints the address, not the content.

Comment: That makes lot more sense. So C-Strings are treated bit differently than normal pointers with the << operator.

Comment: Small suggestion, but I would use ````std::adressof```` to better show intent.

Comment: @xboi209 Thanks for a great suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Run this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

template <class type>
void printAddresses(type *item, int n)
{
    cout << "Printing Addresses..." << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Index " << i << ": " << ((&item) + i)  << endl;
        cout << "Index2 " << i << ": " << (void*) &item[i] << endl;
    }

}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "This is a test";
    printAddresses(str, strlen(str));
}
```

which in my machine prints:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras-A15:~$ g++ -Wall main.cpp
gsamaras@gsamaras-A15:~$ ./a.out
Printing Addresses...
Index 0: 0x7ffd5c9ead58
Index2 0: 0x7ffd5c9ead90
Index 1: 0x7ffd5c9ead60
Index2 1: 0x7ffd5c9ead91
Index 2: 0x7ffd5c9ead68
Index2 2: 0x7ffd5c9ead92
Index 3: 0x7ffd5c9ead70
Index2 3: 0x7ffd5c9ead93
Index 4: 0x7ffd5c9ead78
Index2 4: 0x7ffd5c9ead94
Index 5: 0x7ffd5c9ead80
Index2 5: 0x7ffd5c9ead95
Index 6: 0x7ffd5c9ead88
Index2 6: 0x7ffd5c9ead96
Index 7: 0x7ffd5c9ead90
Index2 7: 0x7ffd5c9ead97
Index 8: 0x7ffd5c9ead98
Index2 8: 0x7ffd5c9ead98
Index 9: 0x7ffd5c9eada0
Index2 9: 0x7ffd5c9ead99
Index 10: 0x7ffd5c9eada8
Index2 10: 0x7ffd5c9ead9a
Index 11: 0x7ffd5c9eadb0
Index2 11: 0x7ffd5c9ead9b
Index 12: 0x7ffd5c9eadb8
Index2 12: 0x7ffd5c9ead9c
Index 13: 0x7ffd5c9eadc0
Index2 13: 0x7ffd5c9ead9d
```

Now **think** what sequence you expect to see for stored chars? You expect every character to be adjacent to the previous one (of course) and every one to take 1 memory cell. That should tell you that:

> (void*) &item[i]

is the right thing to do.

---

Also notice that zmbq's comment, about using a debugger to find out makes sense too.

---

Finally, I would advice you to read: [Printing array element memory adresses C and C++, why different output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239833/printing-array-element-memory-adresses-c-and-c-why-different-output)

Answer (score 0):

A possible way could be to use the C-style `printf` with `%p`. So include [`<cstdio>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c) then try for example:

```
 const char *sp = "abcde" + 2; // some computation giving a string address
 printf("sp=%p ('%s')\n", sp, sp);
```

Alternatively, cast to `(void*)` and use usual

```
std::cout << "sp at " << (void*)sp << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get a different memory address is because your code is wrong.

```
void printAddresses(type *item, int n)
```

`item` is a pointer parameter to your `printAddresses` template function. So, in the following expression:

```
    cout << "Index " << i << ": " << ((&item) + i)  << endl;
```

Therefore:

```
&item
```

becomes the address of the parameter to your template function, and not the address of the array.

This is why:

```
 (&item)+i
```

is wrong, and is utterly meaningless. The address of the parameter to your template function is not really very useful, here.

```
 (void*) &item[i]
```

Is the correct answer.

Comment: Hi can you tell me why ``cout << "Index " << i << ": " << (item + i) << endl;`` not work?

Comment: Because `byte` is, most likely, a `char`, so `std::ostream` will attempt to print a character string, rather than a pointer address. It looks no different than passing any other, arbitrary `char *` to `operator<<`.