# method is not returing a valid pointer

Tags: c++

**NOTE:** I have found the problem. In `Wire.cpp`, i used

```
Wire::Wire(Node* a, Node* b)
{

}
```

which should be

```
Wire::Wire(Node* a, Node* b) : input(a),output(b)
{

}
```

**My original question is below:**

I have two classes `Node.h` and `Wire.h`. When i call the method `getInput()` of `class Wire`, it is supposed to return a pointer but it simply gives an integer value.

**Problem:** In **`void Node::eval()`**, i am calling `input[0]->getInput()->getState()`. I debugged using a print statement in `Node* Wire::getInput()` and found that the program enters into that method. But that method should return a valid pointer so that i can call next method `void Node::getState()`. But then i get **`segmentation fault`**

**`Wire.h`**

```
class Node;

class Wire{
private:
    Node* input;
    Node* output;

public:
    Wire(Node* a, Node* b);
    Node* getInput();
    Node* getOutput();

};
```

**`wire.cpp`**

```
Wire::Wire(Node* a, Node* b)
{

}

Node* Wire::getInput(){
    cout<<"\nInput: "<<input;
    return input;
}

Node* Wire::getOutput(){
    return output;
}
```

**`Node.h`**

```
typedef enum {
    UNDEFINED, INPUT, OUTPUT, AND, NAND, OR, NOR, NOT, XOR
} TGate;

class Node{
private:
    TGate gateType; //Type of the Node
    string name; //Name of the gate (the name of the output in .bench file)
    vector<Wire*> inputs;       
    vector<Wire*> outputs;      
    int state;                  

public:

    void addOutput(Wire *a);                
    void addInput(Wire *a);             


    Node* getInput(unsigned int i);     
    Node* getOutput(unsigned int i);        

    void setState(int st);              
    int  getState(void);            


};
```

**`node.cpp`**

```
void Node::addInput(Wire *a)
{
    inputs.push_back(a);
}

void Node::addOutput(Wire *a)
{
    outputs.push_back(a);
}

string Node::getName()
{
    return name;
}

void Node::setState(int st)         
{
    state = st;

    cout<<"\nState set to: "<<state;
}
int Node::getState(void)
{
    //return 0;
    return state;

}

void Node::eval()
{
    if(inputs[0]->getInput()->getState() == 1)
        cout<<"Node is in rest state."
}
```

**`main()`**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Node* b=new Node(INPUT, "B");
    Node* a=new Node(INPUT, "A");
    Node* Cin=new Node(INPUT, "Cin");
    Node* d=new Node(XOR, "D");
    Wire* w=new Wire(a,d);
    d->addInput(w);
    a->addOutput(w);
    w=new Wire(b,d);
    d->addInput(w);
    b->addOutput(w);
    Node* e=new Node(AND, "E");
    w=new Wire(d,e);
    e->addInput(w);
    d->addOutput(w);
    w=new Wire(Cin,e);
    e->addInput(w);
    Cin->addOutput(w);
    Node* f=new Node(AND, "F");
    w=new Wire(a,f);
    f->addInput(w);
    a->addOutput(w);
    w=new Wire(b,f);
    f->addInput(w);
    b->addOutput(w);
    Node* s=new Node(XOR, "S");
    w=new Wire(d,s);
    s->addInput(w);
    d->addOutput(w);
    w=new Wire(Cin,s);
    s->addInput(w);
    Cin->addOutput(w);
    Node* Cout=new Node(OR, "Cout");
    w=new Wire(e,Cout);
    Cout->addInput(w);
    e->addOutput(w);
    w=new Wire(f,Cout);
    Cout->addInput(w);
    f->addOutput(w);
    Node* out_s=new Node(OUTPUT, "S");
    w=new Wire(s,out_s);
    out_s->addInput(w);
    s->addOutput(w);
    Node* out_Cout=new Node(OUTPUT,"Cout");
    w=new Wire(Cout,out_Cout);
    out_Cout->addInput(w);
    Cout->addOutput(w);

    vector<Node*> inputs;
    vector<Node*> gates;
    vector<Node*> outputs;

    inputs.push_back(a);
    inputs.push_back(b);
    inputs.push_back(Cin);
    gates.push_back(d);
    gates.push_back(e);
    gates.push_back(f);
    gates.push_back(Cout);
    gates.push_back(s);
    outputs.push_back(out_s);
    outputs.push_back(out_Cout);


    //simulate circuit for 5 random inputs  
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) 
    {
        for(unsigned int j=0;j<inputs.size();j++) 
        {
            inputs[j]->setState(rand()%2);
            cout << inputs[j]->getState();
        }
        cout <<" - ";

        for(unsigned int j=0;j<gates.size();j++)
        {   
            gates[j]->eval();
        }

    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Care to paste the complete program?

Comment: @tenfour: i have already posted the failing function. `getInput()` should return a pointer but it is not.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you've pasted. Problem is somewhere else which is why people may want to see the complete program.

Comment: @user2756695 I assume that `input` attribute is being initialized with `a` value. If that is the case, please check that the actual parameter for `a` is a valid address.

Comment: Hunch: You have built the wire with pointers to local node variables or vice versa.

Comment: I suppose you are sure that the `inputs` vector is not empty? Anyway it's good idea to add a check for it into `Node::eval()`: `if( !inputs.empty() ){your_code}` Show us how do you create wires and nodes please.

Comment: `inputs` is not empty. I already printed their values

Comment: Your order of creation should be something like `Node * A = new Node(); Node * B = new Node(); Wire * w = new Wire( A, B ); A->addOutput(w); B->addInput(w); B->eval();`, double-check that.

Comment: The segmentation fault is caused by a part of the code you did not include here. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Wimmel: Ok, i have updated the whole code. There's nothing left

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: My order is similar...please have a look at my updated `main()`

Comment: Well, it _looks_ Ok (unfortunately I don't have a compiler right now since I'm writing this on a mobile device)... I suggest you to reduce the number of nodes created (try 3 nodes - 1 input, 1 bridge and 1 output), and see if the error persists. It will be much easier to debug with a smaller amount of nodes.

Comment: OMG the pointers the pointers. Why are you dynamically allocating everything?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29) are integer values identifying an specific byte on your memory map.

I think that what you really want is the pointer to be printed following a format suggesting the value is an address. For example, `0xHEX_VAL`

Just like at this question: [How to simulate printf's %p format when using std::cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657123/how-to-simulate-printfs-p-format-when-using-stdcout)

**EDIT:**

After you updated your code, I can see you are not initializing `input` neither `output` attributes.

Try with whis constructor for `Wire` class:

```
Wire::Wire(Node* a, Node* b)
{
    input = a;
    output = b;
}
```

Comment: please see my updated question....the problem is not just printing the address. The `getInput()` should return a valid pointer so that i can call the next method (i.e. `getState()`)

Comment: @user2756695 To help you with that, we'll need more information on how `input` attribute is initialized.

Comment: i have updated the code for `node.cpp` also which contains `getState();`

Comment: Yes, thats solved the problem but could you please tell why do i need to do so?

Comment: @user2756695 Because otherwise, you are not telling in your program that `input` acquire `a` value nor `output` is acquiring `b` value. You have to assign `input` an `output` values in your `Wire` object, how? By assigning them at the class constructor, with which values? The ones your are passing as constructor parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Cast to void*, you should see the output in hexadecimal. That is what you need.

`cout<<"\n Input address: "<<(void *)(inputs[0]->getInput());`

Comment: please see my updated question....the problem is not just printing the address. The `getInput()` should return a valid pointer so that i can call the next method (i.e. `getState()`)