# Testing the endianness of a machine

Tags: c, endianness

Here is the program I used:

```
int hex = 0x23456789;
char * val = &hex;
printf("%p\n",hex);
printf("%p %p %p %p\n",*val,*(val+1),*(val+2),*(val+3));
```

Here is my output:

```
0x23456789
0xffffff89 0x67 0x45 0x23
```

I am working on a 64 bit CPU with a 64 bit OS. This shows my machine is little endian. Why is the first byte 0xffffff89? Why the ff's?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you should be using %x since those aren't pointers.

The %x specifiers expect an integer. Because you are passing in a value of type 'char', which is a signed type, the value is being converted to an integer and being sign extended. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension

That essentially means that it takes the most significant bit and uses it for all the higher bits. So 0x89 => 0b10001001 , which has a highest bit of '1' becomes 0xFFFFFF89.

The proper solution is to  specify a 'length' parameter options. You can get more info here: [Printf Placeholders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#Format_placeholders) Essentially, between the '%' and the 'x', you can put extra parameters. 'hh' means that you are passing a char value.

```
int hex = 0x23456789;
char *val = (char*)&hex;

printf("%x\n",hex);
printf("%hhx %hhx %hhx %hhx\n", val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3]);
```

Comment: `"%p"` expects a `void *`, not an integer. Any pointer will work on most machines but to be technically correct (because of varargs) you should explicitly cast when you use it.

Comment: Also, you need to use `"%hhx"` to print an `unsigned char` value, as opposed to a full-sized `unsigned` value.

Comment: Nice! I knew 'h', but I didn't know 'hh' existed, so that's why I had the unsigned casting. I've updated my answer to include this better method.

Answer (score 3):

char is a signed type, it gets promoted to int when passed as an argument.  This promotion causes sign extension.  0x89 is a negative value for char, it gets thus sign-extended to 0xffffff89.  This does not happen for the other values, they don't exceed CHAR_MAX, 127 or 0x7f on the most machines.  You are getting confused by this behavior because you use the wrong format specifier.

Answer (score 2):

%p is asking [printf to format it as an address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369541/where-is-p-useful-with-printf), you are actaully passing a value (*val)

On a 64 bit machine pointer addresses are 64bit, so printf is adding the ffff to pad the fields

Comment: Why isn't it doing it for the other values? like 0xffffff67. I used %x instead of %p and I get the same output.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour, you are asking it to print as an a address a value that isn't an address. So it could be using the next value on the stack, or it could print pink unicorns

Comment: @Bruce: Because it's getting sign-extended. I'm betting it'll change if you declare `val` as an `unsigned char*` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As @Martin Beckett said, `%p` asks `printf` to print a pointer, which is equivalent to `%#x` or `%#lx` (the exact format depends on your OS).

This means `printf` expect an `int` or a `long` (again depends on OS), but you are only supplying it with `char` so the value is up-cast to the appropriate type.

When you cast a smaller signed number to a bigger signed number you have to do something called [sign extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) in order to preserve the value. In the case of `0x89` this occurs because the sign bit is set, so the upper bytes are `0xff` and get printed because they are significant.

In the case of `0x67`, `0x45`, `0x23` sign extension does not happen because the sign bit is not set, and so the upper bytes are 0s and thus not printed.

Answer (score 1):

I test the endian-ness with the condition `((char)((int)511) == (char)255)`. True means little, false means big.

I have tested this on a few separate systems, both little and big, using gcc with optimizations off and to max. In every test I have done I have gotten correct results.

You could put that condition in an if of your application before it needs to do endian-critical operations. If you only want to guarentee you are using the right endian-ness for your entire application, you could instead use a static assertion method such as follows:

```
extern char ASSERTION__LITTLE_ENDIAN[((char)((int)511) == (char)255)?1:-1];
```

That line in the global scope will create a compile error if the system is not little endian and will refuse to compile. If there was no error, it compiles perfectly as if that line didn't exist. I find that the error message is pretty descriptive:

```
error: size of array 'ASSERTION__LITTLE_ENDIAN' is negative
```

Now if you're paranoid of your compiler optimizing the actual check away like I am, you can do the following:

```
int endian;
{
    int i = 255;
    char * c = &i;
    endian = (c[0] == (char)255);
}
if(endian) // if endian is little
```

Which compacts nicely in to this macro:

```
#define isLittleEndian(e) int e; { int i = 255; char * c = &i; e = (c[0] == (char)255); }
isLittleEndian(endian);
if(endian) // if endian is little
```

Or if you use GCC, you can get away with:

```
#define isLittleEndian ({int i = 255; char * c = &i; (c[0] == (char)255);})
if(isLittleEndian) // if endian is little
```

Comment: could you please explain the first line of your answer?