# Write own printf function, trying to include %p.

Tags: c, printf

So I'm writing my own printf function so I'm using stdarg.h and the system call write(). But I have no idea on how to incorrect %p into my function. Would %X produce the same result?

I have %x done as so:

```
'x': x=va_arg(argp,argp, unsigned int); 
     char *temp = convert(x,16);
     write(1, temp, lengthOFtemp);
     break;

char *convert(unsigned int, int)
{
static char buf[33];
char *ptr;

ptr=&buf[sizeof(buff)-1];
*ptr='\0';
do
{
*--ptr="0123456789abcdef"[num%base];
num/=base;
}while(num!=0);

return(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369541/where-is-p-useful-with-printf

Comment: You need to select an integral type that can hold a pointer and cast your pointer to it. This is inherently non-portable. On a 64-bit system you may have to use `unsigned long long int` and `%llX` or similar.On a 32-bit system, `unsigned int` and `%X` may work.

Comment: How can I check to see if the system is 64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: @n.m.: For systems which support `<stdint.h>`, including C99 compliant systems and MSVC, you can use `uintptr_t`.  This is portable.

Comment: Your sample code doesn't compile, and isn't even close. You have parameters without names, mix of `buf` and `buff`, and more and more.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: yes, but what format character corresponds to it?

Comment: @n.m.: the `PRIxPTR` macro from `<inttypes.h>`, but I don't think that's relevant because the asker is implementing `printf()` and is writing the conversion conversion code rather than relying on library functions.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I mean, he cannot portably use an existing integer format of *his own* printf function, or at least it is not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between %p and %X is that pointer sizes are platform specific - 8 bytes on 64-bit platforms, 4 bytes on 32-bit platforms. Thus, you must use an 'unsigned long' variable to handle the pointer argument from va_args, not 'unsigned int' which remains 4 bytes on some 64-bit platforms.

Otherwise yes, very much like the %X code you have above.

Comment: Thanks. how would I check the system platform (X-bit) and then run %p?

Comment: No check needed, just use 'unsigned long'. It will size accordingly for ILP32 and LP64 (32-bit and 64-bit) systems.

Comment: So p=va_arg(argp,argp, unsigned long); will work for both? Then I just have to just do convert(p,16)?

Comment: You must make sure you read the right number of bytes from the stack with va_arg. Thus, if the parameter is %X, you are expecting an integer which is 4 bytes. If the parameter is %p you are expecting a pointer, which is as I explained. Thus you need different calls to va_arg for each.

Comment: Use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` to store a pointer to void (`void *`) as an integer value in a portable manner.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to use

```
void * pv = va_arg(va, void*)
```

to pull the pointer from the variadic argument list.

*To safely receive pointers this way the caller of the variadic function, which does the pulling as shown above, needs to pass in pointers as being casted to `void *`.*

Then do the conversion to integer like so:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
...
uintptr_t uipv = (uintptr_t) pv;
```

and finally call a conversion function:

```
char buff[64] = {0};
char * pc = convert_uintptr(uipv, 16);
```

with:

```
char * convert_uintptr(uintptr_t uipv, unsigned base);
```