# Does %p print the address of the variable as a pointer, or does it print what it points to?

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I have read at least a dozen articles on %p now and I'm still not getting a clear answer on this. I realize there are multiple posts on this on the site and I read a good number of them. [I even read this article, but it did not explain it adequately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369541/where-is-p-useful-with-printf)

Say I have:

```
int x = 10;
void *p = &x;
```

does the below statement print out the address of 'p' or the address of 'x'?

```
printf( "Here: %p\n" , p );
```

I am trying to get the address of x through p.

---

For some context, I am iterating up the stack looking for pointers pointing into a linked list I created:

```
void foo(){

    register void* base asm("ebp");
    void* iter = base;

    void* mBase = MAIN_BASE; //global defined as "register void* base asm("ebp")" in main function

    void* start = &head;
    void* fin = &tail + sizeof( tail );

    while( iter != mBase ){

        if( iter >= start && iter <= fin )
            fprintf( stdout, ">>>>%p\n", iter );

        printf("iter: %p\n", iter );
        iter = (void*)( (char*)iter + 1 );
    }
}
```

Comment: It prints the value of the variable "p", which is the address of the thing "p" points to.

Comment: Is that right? Because in the example I provide, the print out of "iter" is always sequentially the next thing, shouldn't I be seeing some variations if it were returning the pointer's target?

Comment: Who said anything about `p` having to be stored on the stack? Your compiler could be optimizing it out and only ever having `p` stored in registers.

Comment: There are two examples, I'm talking about `iter`, not `p`

Comment: The "pointer's target" is the storage location addressed by the value of the pointer.  When you increment iter by 1 the printed address will increment by 1.  (Of course, the "object" at that address may not be a valid object of any sort, and in fact the storage may not even be allocated.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It prints the **contents** of variable p, which happens to be the address of x, so it prints the address of x. It displays it using the address format for a particular architecture. Format that may vary from one architecture to another: a variable stored in a far segment data, could be printed with a totally different format using a C compiler that produces MS DOS real mode executables, such as `025A:0008` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

The statement prints the address of `x`, because this is the value stored in `p`. Of course `p` does not need to be valid, or to point to anything in particular.

In general, functions cannot take an address of a variable without you explicitly obtaining the address with the `&` operator. So if you wanted to print the address of `p`, you would have to do this:

```
 printf( "Here: %p\n" , (void*)&p );
```

Comment: But of course it's entirely possible that "p", in the general case, does not point at any existing object.

Answer (score 1):

With this kind of doubt, it usually helps me to printf both the address and the value of p and x.
I've tried this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int x = 10;
    void *p = &x;

    printf("value of x : %d\n", x);
    printf("value of x address in mem: %d\n", (int) &x);
    printf("value of p (integer): %d\n", (int)p);
    printf("value of p address in mem: %d\n", (int) &p);

}
```

And the output of this code is:

value of x : 10

value of x address in mem: -1079190472

value of p: -1079190472

value of p address in mem: -1079190468

You can see that the value stored in p is the address of x.

Answer (score 0):

It will print address of x because when we are saying

```
int *p=&x;
```

we are bascically doing these two steps:

```
int *p;
p=&x;
```

so `p` will store address of `x`.