# what will happen if we use %p instead of %d while printing an int

Tags: c, pointers, int

Can someone explain the output of the 2nd line?

```
int x=10;
printf("%d\n",x);
printf("%p\n",x);
printf("%p\n",&x);
```

Output:

```
10
0000000a
006aff0c
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369541/where-is-p-useful-with-printf

Comment: Well, it is undefined behavior to use mismatched `printf()` conversion specifiers and arguments; that said, `0000000a` is the hex representation for decimal `10`.

Comment: Printing integers using `%p` is not guaranteed to work (and, under not uncommon circumstances, such as 64-bit programming, is pretty much guaranteed not to work), but how surprising is it that 10 (base 10) comes out as 0x0a (base 16)?

Comment: looks like %p always converts anything that went through him into  Hexadecimal 
@DavidBowling

Comment: @ToufiqueImam-- not exactly; the `%p` conversion specifier prints the value of a pointer [in an implementation-defined way](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8). This may or may not be a hexadecimal representation. Note that pointers must be cast to `(void *)` before printing with `%p` to avoid undefined behavior; e.g., `printf("%p\n",(void *) &x);`

Comment: Yes, it could technically print out the entire text for Macbeth, as long as the implementation doco said that's what it would do :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case, it appears to be treating the value `10` as a pointer and outputting it as an eigth-digit, zero-padded-on-the-left, hexadecimal number<sup>(a)</sup>.

*However,* as per `C11 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function, /9` (all standards quotes below also refer to `C11`):

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. ***If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.***

So, literally, *anything* is permitted to happen. You generally want to avoid undefined behaviour as much as possible, as the behaviour can change between implementations, versions or even the day of the week :-)

There's also technically a problem with your *third* line. The standard states, in `7.21.6.1 /8` for the `p` conversion specifier:

> ***The argument shall be a pointer to void.*** The value of the pointer is
>   converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined
>   manner.

Since `&x` is actually a pointer to `int`, this puts it in violation of the same contract. You should probably use something like this instead:

```
printf ("%p\n", (void*)(&x));
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> What it *actually* does is implementation-defined, as per the second sentence in the final quote above. It can basically do anything, provided the implementation documents it, as specified in `J.3 Implementation-defined behavior`:

> A conforming implementation is required to document its choice of behavior in each of the areas listed in this subclause.